# Why the SceneKit Material looks different, even when the image is the same?

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

The material content support many options to be loaded, two of these are NSImage (or UIImage) and SKTexture.

I noticed when loading the same image file (.png)  with different loaders, the material is rendered different.

I'm very sure it is an extra property loaded from SpriteKit transformation, but I don't know what is it.

Why the SceneKit Material looks different, even when the image is the same?

This is the rendered example:

[image]

About the code:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.green
```

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSImage(named: "texture")
```

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = SKTexture(imageNamed: "texture")
```

The complete example is here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SceneKitExamples/tree/master/MaterialTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has something to do with color spaces/gamma correction. My guess is that textures loaded via the `SKTexture(imageNamed:)` initializer aren't properly gamma corrected. You would think this would be documented somewhere, or other people would have noticed, but I can't seem to find anything.

Here's some code to swap with the last image in your linked sample project. I've force unwrapped as much as possible for brevity:

```swift
      // Create the texture using the SKTexture(cgImage:) init 
      // to prove it has the same output image as SKTexture(imageNamed:)
      let originalDogNSImage = NSImage(named: "dog")!
      var originalDogRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: originalDogNSImage.size.width, height: originalDogNSImage.size.height)
      let originalDogCGImage = originalDogNSImage.cgImage(forProposedRect: &originalDogRect, context: nil, hints: nil)!
      let originalDogTexture = SKTexture(cgImage: originalDogCGImage)

      // Create the ciImage of the original image to use as the input for the CIFilter 
      let imageData = originalDogNSImage.tiffRepresentation!
      let ciImage = CIImage(data: imageData)
      
      // Create the gamma adjustment Core Image filter
      let gammaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGammaAdjust")!
      gammaFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
      // 0.75 is the default. 2.2 makes the dog image mostly match the NSImage(named:) intializer
      gammaFilter.setValue(2.2, forKey: "inputPower")
      
      // Create a SKTexture using the output of the CIFilter
      let gammaCorrectedDogCIImage = gammaFilter.outputImage!
      let gammaCorrectedDogCGImage = CIContext().createCGImage(gammaCorrectedDogCIImage, from: gammaCorrectedDogCIImage.extent)!
      let gammaCorrectedDogTexture = SKTexture(cgImage: gammaCorrectedDogCGImage)
      
      // Looks bad, like in StackOverflow question image.
//        let planeWithSKTextureDog = planeWith(diffuseContent: originalDogTexture)
      // Looks correct
        let planeWithSKTextureDog = planeWith(diffuseContent: gammaCorrectedDogTexture)
```

Using a `CIGammaAdjust` filter with an `inputPower` of 2.2 makes the `SKTexture` almost? match the `NSImage(named:)` init. I've included the original image being loaded through `SKTexture(cgImage:)` to rule out any changes caused by using that initializer versus the `SKTexture(imageNamed:)` you asked about.

Comment: Omg!! Thanks!! It works great, testing a little bit I found that closest to gamma is 1.75 I will update the answer for future searches. Thank you very much!